# Multiple dropdown dialogs in the same window?

Tags: syntax, input, dialog-window

Consider a few dropdown dialogs:

```
dropdownDialog[list_, phrase_] := 
 DialogInput[{choice = ""}, 
  Column[{TextCell[phrase], PopupMenu[Dynamic[choice], list], 
    Button["OK", DialogReturn[choice]]}]]

d1:=
dropdownDialog[{"A1","A2"}, "Q1"]
d2:=
dropdownDialog[{"A3","A4"}, "Q2"]
```

How do you display two dialogs in the same window so that the user may submit the answers simultaneously (i.e., not in two sequential windows, the second one appearing after the selection in the first one has been made)?

[image]

Comment: I think that you don't want to use `SetDelayed` for `d1` and `d2`. I.e. just do `d1 = dropdownDialog[{"A1", "A2"}, "Q1"]`.

Comment: @lericr : but then, if launch just d1; d2;, I will get first the window with `d1` and then, later, another window with `d2`.

Comment: Ah. I was confused. So, do you want values assigned to d1,d2 or do you want a list of vaues? But regardless, you're going to need to create a function that creates the complete dialog based on a set of "specifications".

Comment: Do you need `DialogInput` or would `FormObject` work?

Comment: @lericr : I need to choose one of the fixed answers. If I understand correctly, FormObject would not work for this.

Comment: I’m so confused. You want to display both simultaneously, but you only want to choose one?

Comment: Do you want multiple values as a result, like in a list? Or do you want one final value as an answer?

Comment: @lericr : excuse me; I want them to be displayed in one window, one below another, say, Q1 with its choice list, and below Q2 with its choice list, and below the "Submit" button.

Comment: @lericr : and each of the choices will be assigned to its own value.

Comment: And what do you expect to happen when user hits Submit?

Comment: Okay, a FormObject can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer after question edit:

```
choicesDialog[spec_List] := DialogInput[
  {choice = spec[[All, 2, 1]]},
  Column[Flatten@{
     Table[With[{i = i},
       Row[{TextCell[spec[[i, 1]]], 
         PopupMenu[Dynamic[choice[[i]]], spec[[i, 2]]]}]
       ]
      , {i, Length@spec}
      ],
     Button["OK", DialogReturn[choice]]}]]

{d1, d2} = choicesDialog[{{"Q1", {"A1", "A2"}}, {"Q2", {"A3", "A4"}}}]
```

---

Old answer

```
dropdownDialog // ClearAll

dropdownDialog[Dynamic@var_, list_, phrase_] := CreateDialog[
  DynamicModule[{choice = ""}, 
    Column[{
     TextCell[phrase],
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[choice], list],
     Button["OK", DialogReturn[var = choice]]
     }]
   ]]

dropdownDialog[Dynamic@d1, {"A1", "A2"}, "Q1"]
dropdownDialog[Dynamic@d2, {"A3", "A4"}, "Q2"]
```

After clicking OK you can evaluate `d1` and `d2` to confirm the values were set.

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I was looking for. I have added an image to the question body illustrating it.

Comment: @JohnTaylor ok, please check the edit,